# python pandas read json gzip file from s3

Tags: pandas, aws-lambda, gzip, python-3.8

I'm trying this in `aws lambda`. When an exception occurs, message e is printed.(refer below code)

But there is no exception message. so I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
import boto3
import gzip
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')    
response = s3.Object(bucket, 'test.gzip')

try:
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response.get()["Body"], mode='rb') as gzipfile:
        print(f'gzipfile : {gzipfile}') 
        # gzipfile : <gzip botocore.response.StreamingBody object as 0x7fcffd362250 0x7fcffd3d00d0>
        # df = pd.read_json(content.read(), lines=True)
        # df = pd.read_json(content, lines=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

--

```
df = pd.read_json(response.get()["Body"], lines=Truem compression='gzip')
```

--

I tried the above codes.

On all tries, the program either ends with no results within the specified Lambda time(10 minutes) or without an exception message.

How can I read `json gzip` from s3 and make it into pandas dataframe?

Comment: Have you defined a 'handler' function within your lambda ?

Comment: @DanielWeigel yes, I have. I'll edit the code in the question. Thanks

Comment: all things are in lambda_handeler(event, context) function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the function configured to run in a VPC?

Answer (score 0):

I use gzip like this:

```
obj =boto3.resource('s3').Object(bucket, key)
data = gzip.decompress(obj.get()['Body'].read())
df = pd.dataframe(data)
```